# Swift compare arrays, anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Tags: arrays, swift, compare

Could someone tell me how I can solve this problem? I have two arrays in array 1 change values, array 2 has to synchronize with the first one, but without losing the value positions. I have tried with `difference(from:)` but it reorders the values of array 2. Here as it should be, thank you very much for your help.

```swift
let array1 = ["01", "06", "17", "22", "33", "45", "04"]
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "10", "01", "34"]

//
...
// Result
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "01", "06", "33", "45"]
```

The order of the values in array 2 must remain the same, delete those missing from array 1 and add those missing from array 1 to the end of array 2.

Comment: What does synchronize mean here? How should the two arrays be combined? But I agree that you will most likely need to loop over one or both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution:

1. Copy array1 to a temporary var `temp`
2. Loop through the indexes of `temp` in reverse order. If a value from `temp` exists in array2, remove it.
3. Append `temp` to array2.

That would have poor (roughly `O(n^2)`, or rather `O(array1.count*array2.count)`) time performance for large arrays, since the array `contains()` function is `O(n)`. You could speed it up by using a set to track items in `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I can get

```swift
let array1 = ["01", "06", "17", "22", "33", "45", "04"]
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "10", "01", "34"]

let remove = (array2.filter{!array1.contains($0)})
let append = (array1.filter{!array2.contains($0)})
for i in remove {
    array2 =  array2.filter {$0 != i}
}
array2.append(contentsOf: append)

print("array2:\(array2)")
// array2:["04", "17", "22", "01", "06", "33", "45"]
```

Comment: You aren’t using any of the temp variables so you can remove those lines.

Comment: Joakim Danielson. Thanks for your comment, you're right, I don't know how I didn't notice , I'll correct it.

Comment: While this may be a good solution for the given use case, it has one drawback.  It does not indicate, to someone looking at your code in the future, that you expect the arrays to contain unique values. For this you should be using Swift's OrderedSet functionality.  See https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/tree/main.